# Can you tell me what is this component

Tags: components, card

I found this electronic component in the road, but I can't tell what it's tend to be because I'm not an electronics guy, can you please tell me what is it ?
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which component are you asking about? or do you mean the whole board? If the whole board, there's a big hint on the label. Just identify the serial pins, hook up a terminal, and ask it.

Comment: And a quick search yields this potentially useful link : http://d.pcnews.at/ins/cds/005/prg/DEB/mon552.asm

Comment: Looks pretty cool what ever it is.

Comment: Lots of replaceable ICs with fancy chips in fancy slots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an older type of small microcomputer with program stored in battery-backed RAM. It has a serial interface and an 8-bit 8051-core processor.

Not very amazing these days. It has a static 32K x 8 RAM. You can probably talk to it via that 2x5 port on the lower right-hand side by the MAX232. Probably powered via the grey terminal block.